# need to validate a input text field

Tags: apex, inputtext

I have a input text field for search option.
when the input field is empty or contain a single character i need to throw a error message
"Input box must contain atleast two characters"

**my VF:**

```
<center><apex:inputText id="theTextInput2"  value="{!CityI}" label="City"/> 
 <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!Search}"  reRender="tblZoneContacts1"/></center><br></br>
```

**controller:**

```
public void Search(){  
    if(CityI==null || CityI==''){
        Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'search term must be longer than one character:'));
        return;
}
```

***Thanks in Advance***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include an else part in your code to check for the length of the string Cityl, if it is less than 2 characters. If less than 2 characters then throw an error.

```
public void Search()
{
 if(CityI==null || CityI=='')
 { 
 Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'search term must be   longer than one character:')); 
 return; 
 }
 else if (CityI.length()<2)
 {
 Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Input box must contain at least two characters')); 
 return; 
 }
}
```